# Getting exception while sending avro message, exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema:

Tags: java, spring-boot, avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I am using spring cloud stream and trying to publish an avro message but getting the above exception,

I have below properties,

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.feed-output-channel.producer.useNativeEncoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.feed-output-channel.destination=TOPI.NAME
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.feed-output-channel.producer.partition-count=1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.feed-output-channel.contentType=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.feed-output-channel.producer.partition-key-expression=headers['kafka_messageKey']
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.feed-output-channel.producer.configuration.request.timeout.ms=60000


spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.schema.avro.dynamicSchemaGenerationEnabled=true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.url=https://base-url:8081/
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=g-vmx.com:9092,g-vmx.com:9092,g-vmx.com:9092
```

I have added the confluentSchema registry beam also, have `@EnableSchemaRegistryClient` annotation n main class

```
@Bean
@Primary
public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient() {
  log.info("schema registry bean");
  ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient client = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
  client.setEndpoint(endPoint);
  return client;
}
```

Code where I am pushing the message

```
public void publishFeed(String market, String sku) {
  token.link();
  MessageChannel messageChannel = resolveMessageChannel();
  String messageKey = String.format("%s_%s", market, sku);

  Payload Payload = buildPayload(market, sku);
  Message<RequestPayload> message = MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(payload)
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, messageKey)
        .build();
  log.info("publish requestPayload message {} ", message);
  boolean sent = messageChannel.send(message, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_TO_SEND_MESSAGE);
  if (!sent) {
    throw new MessagePublishException("Unable to send=" + message);
  }
}
```

Dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-schema:2.2.1.RELEASE'
implementation "io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.3.0"
implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.1"
```

At this `messageChannel.send(message, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_TO_SEND_MESSAGE);` line it throw exception.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@1dc8da99]; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema:
```

Not able to figure out why it's throwing this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to publish the message in AVRO format successfully,
Though, the above configuration and properties are enough for publishing a message in AVRO format. It's working in other application but not in my app.

**So I added below properties.**  **After that it was successful**

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.basic.auth.user.info=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.ssl.key.password=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.basic.auth.user.info=
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.schema.registry.auto.register.schemas=false
```

***Though I already had the certificate information defined under below properties***  but it didn't work with these properties , had to add the above properties

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.keystore.location`
`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.ssl.truststore.location` with other properties